# Need help for remote validation for check email exist or not using angular IO

Tags: angular

I have tried to call remote validation by using below code

In component file

Validation code

```
this.formCompany = this.fb.group({
    varEmail: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(150),this.emailExist.bind(this)])],
}});
```

function for check email exist or not

```
emailExist(control: FormControl) {

    if(control.value) {  
      this.services.emailExist(control.value).subscribe(res => {this.checkEmailExist = res;
        if(this.checkEmailExist.exist > 0) {
            return { 'emailexist': true };
        } else {
             return null;
        }
        } );
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

HTML Code

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap="wrap">
   <md-input-container class="ml-xs mr-xs" style="width: 60%">
      <input mdInput placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="150"  [ngModel]="CompanyEdit.varEmail" [formControl]="formCompany.controls['varEmail']">
   </md-input-container>
<small *ngIf="formCompany.controls['varEmail'].hasError('required') && formCompany.controls['varEmail'].touched" class="mat-text-warn">Please insert email address.</small>
<small *ngIf="formCompany.controls['varEmail'].hasError('maxlength') && formCompany.controls['varEmail'].touched" class="mat-text-warn">Email address can not exceed 150 characters.</small>
<small *ngIf="formCompany.controls['varEmail'].hasError('emailexist') && formCompany.controls['varEmail'].touched" class="mat-text-warn">Email address already exist.</small>
</div>
```

This code not working.

Comment: if the email exist the control is valid , else it's not valid , that's what you want ?

Comment: right but here i have call service by `this.services` . So it give me an error of that the **Cannot read property 'services' of undefined**. I have used same service for insert and update code.

Comment: can u show me your constructor , have u inject `services` ? can you edit the question by setting your full code..(important parts)

Comment: You need to bind `this`, so that `this` will have the scope you want, so do `this.emailExist.bind(this)`

Comment: @AJT_82 you're right ! i forget this poins (y)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this` so that you have have the correct (outside) scope of `this`. By binding `this` you can refer to `this.services` for example (which is outside this `emailExist` function).

I suggest you read this excellent question + answers about the `this`-keyword: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

So what you need to do is simply:

```
this.emailExist.bind(this)
```

in your `Validators` array.

Comment: It working now and got response from service. But validation doesn't work

Comment: Okay... what does *doesn't work* mean? And what is your response if it's valid, what is the response if it's not? You are not setting any validator in the subscribe :)

Comment: Looking closer at your code... having the custom validator... it will call the service really many times... maybe want to rethink that?

Comment: Would you maybe rethink about the request and make the request based on some other condition, because this way is perhaps not the best. This makes a bunch of api calls, and if you do it while typing it wouldn't even have time to execute the previous call....

Comment: Yes right. I have tried to call this service on change but it's not possible to call service on onChange event.